# Trigger for custom dependency properties in Style

Tags: wpf, xaml

## The problem

I defined a reusable control, MyControl, that extends a TextBox.

I want to set a Trigger to one of its dependency properties.
So I added a style to it, with Triggers.

But if I set the TargetType of the Style to MyControl, I get a XAML warning that `'MyControl' TargetType does not match type of element 'TextBlock'`.
And if I set it to TextBlock, I get a compilation error that `The member "MyDependencyProperty" is not recognized or is not accessible.`.

- How can I define this style with the triggers?

---

## Sample

### C# code-behind

```cs
namespace UserControls.Local
{
    public partial class MyControl : TextBlock
    {
        #region Trogdor

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TrogdorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Trogdor", typeof (bool), typeof (MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

        public bool Trogdor
        {
            get { return (bool) GetValue(TrogdorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TrogdorProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion


        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

### XAML

```xml
<TextBlock
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControls.Local"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Text="BOOP!"
    x:Class="UserControls.Local.MyControl">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Trogdor" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DeepPink"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `<MyControl>...</MyControl>` rather than `<TextBlock x:Class="UserControls.Local.MyControl">...</TextBlock>` directly?

Answer (score 11):

The solution I found was to "fully qualify" the dependency property on the binding:

```
<Trigger Property="local:MyControl.Trogdor" Value="True">
```

Comment: Often the simplest solutions are the best.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are still looking for a solution, but the answer [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758836/binding-a-wpf-style-trigger-to-a-custom-dependency-property) worked for me, while yours didn't.

It uses a DataTrigger with a binding on the root element, instead of a Trigger:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Highlight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Elements:DataElement}}}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="{DynamicResource EntryBoxHighlightBackground}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

With your solution, I press the button and the value of the variable changes but the style trigger doesn't apply the changes, like it was not informed of the change in the variable.

Comment: **Why** didn't my solution work? Did it throw a XAML warning? Did it fail to compile? Did it fail to affect the UI?

Comment: @ANeves it compiles, i press the button and the value of the variable changes but the style trigger doesn't apply the changes, like he was not informed of the change in the variable. I've seen answer like yours in other posts but it doesn't seem to work in my case. Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: Your case might not be the same, you might be doing something differently. Otherwise, the solution would work. Can you share a working sample where your solution works and mine doesn't?