# Why not to change dependency property?

Tags: wpf

This is my custom-control code

```
public partial class FlatImageButton : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsActive", typeof(bool?), typeof(FlatImageButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(IsActiveChanged)));
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsActiveProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value);
    }

    public FlatImageButton() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static void IsActiveChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FlatImageButton button = (FlatImageButton)d;

        button.IsActive = (bool) e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

This is custom-control xaml code.
`IsActive` property change the `Background` property.

```
<ContentControl ...>

    <Button x:Name="_Control" Focusable="False">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" />
                    <Border Padding="{Binding ElementName=_Root, Path=Padding}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Image Width="24" Height="24" Source="{Binding ElementName=_Root, Path=Image}" />
                            <TextBlock Name="Text" Text="{Binding ElementName=_Root, Path=Text}" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=_Root, Path=Fill}" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Border.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ElementName=_Root, Path=Background}" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ElementName=_Root, Path=Foreground}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=_Root, Path=IsActive}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ElementName=_Root, Path=Foreground}" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Style>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</ContentControl>
```

A problem occurred when trying to change 'IsActive' in another control.

```
<common:FlatImageButton Tag="{x:Static enum:Coin.ETHEREUM}" x:Name="_CEthereum" Cursor="Hand" Padding="10, 10" Text="{Binding ViewModel.Coin,ElementName=_Root}" Background="#EEE" Foreground="#DDD" Fill="#333" Image="pack://application:,,,/Resources/ethereum.png">
  <common:FlatImageButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="common:FlatImageButton">
      <Setter Property="IsActive" Value="False" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewModel.Coin, ElementName=_Root}" Value="ETHEREUM">
          <Setter Property="IsActive" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </common:FlatImageButton.Style>
</common:FlatImageButton>
```

Why not to change property?

Details:

- ViewModel.Coin value is always ETHEREUM.

Comment: The Text Binding, i.e. `Text="{Binding ViewModel.Coin,ElementName=_Root}"` is working? Try to use the actual enum value instead of a string for the DataTrigger's value, like you did for the Tag property.

Comment: `Text="{Binding ViewModel.Coin,ElementName=_Root}"` is working.

Comment: Ok, did you try `Value="{x:Static enum:Coin.ETHEREUM}"` instead of `Value="ETHEREUM"`?

Comment: Yes. it's not working. :(

Comment: It isn't clear what "not working" really means here. You haven't shown what is supposed to happen when the IsActive property changes. How do you actually know that it does not change?

Comment: I added xaml of FlatImageButton control. Can you check it?

Comment: The other `ElementName=_Root` bindings are working? It's also wrong to register the dependency property with type `bool?` but declare the CLR property wrapper as `bool IsActive`.

Answer (score 0):

The property change callback is not needed actually, you can remove it, just leave the property metadata with `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false)`.

The property change callback is the logic needs to be executed after value has been changed, it is not recommended to change the property value in the callback function.

Comment: I already removed `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata`. However, it's not working.

Comment: While this is of course true, it does not answer the question. It should be a comment instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try Change Your IsActive to common::FlatImageButton.IsActive

You can also see [Trigger for custom dependency properties in Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38574390/trigger-for-custom-dependency-properties-in-style)

Comment: That's not it. I need to use trigger ins another control.

Comment: Two question here :
1. How do you verify that "IsActive" is not working? (e.g. by checking whether the background changes)
2. What is the ElementName "_Root" represent?

A small tip : You can refer to "Output" window when debugging for binding error.